# How did the whole world know about אסתר's beauty?

Tags: talmud-gemara, megillat-esther, talmud-bavli, tractate-megillah, 5-megilloth

In [Megilah 13a](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.13a.11-12?lang=he) it says all the nations of the world knew that אסתר was beautiful?

How did they even know who אסתר is? Let alone, her beauty!

Comment: She was the queen of the King of the largest empire the world had ever seen, by a king who threw parties and invited everyone?